# Difference in modules exporting

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I found that there are 3 ways of exporting modules in Javascript but I'm not really sure how they differ from each other.

Could someone explain how each way is different?

```
const x = function(a,b){
    return (a*b)
};
const y = function(a,b){
    return (a/b)
};

1: module.exports = x;
2: module.exports.x = x;
3: module.exports = {
    x:x,
    y:y
};
```

Comment: Well, the obvious difference is that 1) and 2) don't export `y`…

Comment: Have you read https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `modules.exports` is what a Node.js `require()` call will return after loading the module.

Let's assume your module code is found in `mymod.js`. Then the three listed cases will work like this:

1: `let m = require('mymod'); m(2, 3)`  results in `6`

The export is a single object (the function) only.

2: `let m = require('mymod'); m.x(2, 3)` results in `6`

A single named property is exported. The internal name and exported one does not have to be identical.

3: `let.m = require('mymod'); m.y(6, 2)` results in `3`

Very similar to 2. Just a more compact way for expressing of multipled named properties in one go. Again, the internal names and exported ones don't have to be identical.

Note that ES6 features `export` and `import` keywords built into the language. They were partially inspired by Node.js but have a different syntax and to some degree also different semantics.